# Issue: iOS UITableView scrolling stops other task

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am developing application running based on async socket communication over TCPIP.
Aim of the app is to fetch data cyclicly(2 second) from the server and list down the datas on tableview.

Up to the this point i have done the coding and everything. The app is working fine. 
However, when i start scrolling in the UITableview, cyclic fetching stops until tableviews declares end of scrolling.

Instead of adding all codes i am just adding sample code which is having same behavior.
In this sample project i have created timer.
There is an label to show counter and button to start/stop the timer on the screen. 
In screen i have added also uitextview which has quite long text just have scrolling enabled.

Here is the code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int i;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{



}

@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSTimer *timer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *txtBtn;
- (IBAction)btnStartStop:(id)sender;

@end


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label,txtBtn, timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    i = 0;
    //timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnStartStop:(id)sender {
    if ([txtBtn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
        [txtBtn setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timer_Running) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            NSLog(@"Timer Started");
    }
    else{
        [txtBtn setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Timer Stopped");
    }


}

-(void)timer_Running{
    NSLog(@"Timer Running");
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    i++;
}


@end
```

For the above code;
When you click on the Start button, counter starts and on the label you can see increment  each 1s. But once you touch and scroll up/down on UITextView than count does not increase, just wait until scrolling to end and counter contunious increment.

Can anyone tell me what could be the possible reason and how to avoid this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe show some code on how you're doing the fetch?

Comment: Edit your question to show your code

Comment: I have update the post with codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You need to have your timer initiated from a background thread. Replace the code you have to initiate your timer be this:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                         target:self
                              selector:@selector(timer_Running:)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Secondly, since your timer will now fired in a background thread, you need to access UIKit from the main thread:

```
-(void) timer_Running:(NSTimer *)timer {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Timer Running");
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    });
    i++;
}
```

*Note that the `i++` needs not be scheduled on the main queue.* The code above has been tested with your code and is shown to work.

Comment: I have added full code sample project codes above which is having exactly same behaviour. It seems there is something wrong with timers?

Comment: In your example, you are scheduling your `NSTimer` from the main thread. Since the main thread is busy tracking the tap, drag, and so forth, it cannot also allow the time to fire. The response above addresses this, and provides proper `dispatch_async` as originally suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the same solution that i have found over net.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of above problem and solution about.
Main issue was about the NSRunLoopMode.
If you are using NSTimer or performSelector object, the mode of RunLoopMode is assigned to NSDefaulRunLoopModes by default which is driving Timers to stop while you are scrolling the page. 
The solution is to add the timers and performSelectors to NSRunLoopCommonModes instead of using NSDefaultRunLoopModes.

This is the solution that i have found.

thanks for your support